# Cypher query and Ruby on Rails

Tags: neo4j

I have a Cypher query like this:

```
start n=node(*) match n-[:has_comments]->(m) return n,m;
```

which runs ok.
How can I run this from RoR?
When using Postgres and ActiveModel, in the controller I was able to do use something like this.

```
@query = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <condition>;"
@result = <ClassName>.connection.execute(@query)
```

And after that I processed @result any way I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Neo4j::Session.current.query` to build general Cypher queries. Don't use `START n=node` anymore, that syntax isn't valid in future versions, so you should use `MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) =` instead.

```
query = "MATCH (n)-[:has_comments]->(m) WHERE ID(n) = #{id} RETURN n, m"
result = Neo4j::Session.current.query(query).to_a
```

That'll give you an array of structs, with your results accessible by calling the `n` and `m` methods, respectively. I don't suggest you do it this way at all. As an alternative, you can do this:

```
result = Neo4j::Session.current.query.match("(n)-[:has_comments]->(m)").where("ID(n) = {id}").params(id: id).return(:n, :m)
```

You'll access the data the same way: `n` and `m` methods.

I don't recommend you do that, either. You're using Rails and ActiveNode, so you should have models and be able to do `n_node.as(:n).comments(:m).pluck(:n, :m)`.

Comment: I am going to test them

Comment: For the later query remember that you can do `Neo4j::Session.current.query.match(n: {neo_id: id}).match("n-[:has_comments]->(m)").return(:n, :m)` which is a bit more concise

Comment: I am trying to test the third recommendation, I am using both ActiveNode and ActiveRel, and running  n_node.as(:n).comments(:m).pluck(:n, :m) from console I m getting this error: NameError: undefined local variable or method `n_node' for main:Object
 from (irb):119

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Post a github gist if you'd like but please don't add your code to my post, it appears to come from me.

Comment: OK, how about this error? n_node.as(:n).comments(:m).pluck(:n, :m)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `n_node' for main:Object

Comment: `n_node` is the example I picked to represent your starting node. Change the variable to whatever you are calling it locally.